# Serialize dataGridView to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datagridview, jsonserializer

I have a datagridview on my Windows Form Application that takes input from a user. I'd like to use JSON to store this input and am trying to serialize the input from the datagridview into JSON.

So far I have:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.dataGridView1);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("json.json", output);
    }
```

However something seems to be going wrong in trying to serialize the datagridview (prior I was under the impression any object could be converted?). Does this mean I have to convert the datagridview to an array or a list or something similar before I can serialize it?

Comment: You converting windows forms control, but you want convert data which this control presenting. For the answer you need to provide information how you inserting data in the `DataGridView`

Comment: @Fabio As I said, the data is inserted by a user, the datagridview does not get its data elsewhere. The datagridview IS the method by which data is inserted.

Comment: Always serialize the data, not the view. From reading the docs it seems that DataGridView.DataSource is the object you want to serialize.

Comment: @Skynet that seems to have done the trick, feel free to add it as the solution and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always serialize the data itself and not the view.

In this case you have to serialize the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 4):

You want convert only data, not a windows forms control.

My suggestion to create a class which represent one row of information in `DataGridView`

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then create collection and assign it to the `DataGridView.DataSource`

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<Person> _data;

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create empty collection/datasource
        _data = new BindingList<Person>();

        // This line will generate columns automatically if
        // DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true (by default it is true)
        this.yourDataGridView.DataSource = _data;
    }
}
```

Which you can later serialize

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("json.json", output);
}
```